# Extract substrings from a text file on each line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, text-files

Is there a way to extract substrings from a textfile from each like e.g.
Say this is the text file but with alot more lines like this:

`president, Donald Trump, 74, USA`

`Priminster, Boris Johnson, 56, UK`

I would need to loop through each line and get substrings which are split by commas.
So the that the substring would be `Donald Trump, 74` and so on for the other lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it easily using simple `split()` and `join()` methods of string in python -

### Working Code -

```
# You could open your file like this
#file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r') 

# For now I am assuming your file contains the following line of data. 
# You could uncomment above line and use.

file1 = ['president, Donald Trump, 74, USA','president, Donald Trump, 74, USA']
for line in file1: 
    print("".join(line.split(',')[1:3]))
```

**Output :**

```
Donald Trump, 74
Donald Trump, 74
```

---

### Explanation

- Basically you are just splitting the string ( each line in file ) at comma and converting the string into array. So `line.split(',')` will give -

  ```
   ['president', ' Donald Trump', ' 74', ' USA']
  ```
- Now, we are just joining the 2nd and the 3rd element of the list obtained in the above step. This is done by `",".join()` which will join each elements of list with `','`.
- Also, note that we have used `[1:3]` which will select only the 1st and the 2nd element from the list. So they will give the result which is displayed above

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
with open('data.file') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(', ')
        if len(parts) == 4:
            print(', '.join(parts[1:3]).strip())
```

Output:

```
Donald Trump, 74
Boris Johnson, 56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split, for splitting string at a specific character. You will get a list, that you can join later on. Reading a file is easy.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines()
```

For this specific example you can do

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    row  = "{}, {}".format(line.split(',')[1], line.split(',')[2])
    print(row)
```

Otherwise, please be more clear about what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file, read the file line by line, then use pythons `string.split` method with a delimiter of a comma to get a list of words you can filter through.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    line = my_file.readline()
    while line:
        word_list = line.split(',')
        print(f'{word_list[1]}, {word_list[2]}')
        line = my_file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = []
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    #to save it as a list
    lst.append(stripped_line.split(",")[1:-1])
print(lst)

#to print each of the element
for i in lst:
    print(",".join(i))
```